# Does a Facebook app have to be registered on a personal account, or can we register it on a fan page?

Tags: facebook

When signing in to developer.facebook.com while having a fan page as the identity, it tells me I need to switch to a personal account. Since I would like to create an app for my company I would prefer if it wasn't stored on my personal account, but rather on the company's fan page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a personal account. "Gray Accounts" don´t exist anymore.

Comment: But after you done that you can connect the app to your business in business manager